# ReactJs: Fetch, transform data with function, then setState

Tags: reactjs

I have managed to fetch data from an API successfully. Data transformation of JSON format works too, but i'm having trouble integrating it to "componentDidMount" to set state with a transformed JSON format. I'm getting an undefined state when i `console.log(this.state.races)`.

I'm also getting this error message:

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.

```
class Races extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          races: []};
        this.processResults = this.processResults.bind(this);  
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      fetch(RACE_SERVICE_URL) 
        .then(results => results.json()) 
        .then(this.processResults)
    }

    processResults(data) {

      const raceId_arr = data.map(d => d.raceId);
      const season_arr = data.map(d => d.season);
      const raceName_arr = data.map(d => d.raceName);
      const url_arr = data.map(d => d.url);
      const data_mapped = {'raceId': raceId_arr, 'season': season_arr, 'raceName': raceName_arr, 'url': url_arr};

      this.setState({races:data_mapped});
      console.log(data_mapped);
      console.log(this.state.races);
    }


    render() {
        const title = 'Race Tracks';

        return (
          <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <RacesViz data= {this.state.races.raceId} />
          </div>

        );
    }

}

export default Races;
```

I have also tried:

```
.then(data => this.processResults(data))
```

**What console.log(data_mapped) prints:**

```
{raceId:[1, 2, 3]
raceName:["AGP", "BGP", "CGP"]
season: [2018, 2018, 2018]
url: ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGP", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGP"]}
```

Comment: Are you calling `processData` in your render method or in your child components ?

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is async so you can't get immediate result with `console.log` like you did. Use a callback function instead:

```
this.setState({races:data_mapped}, () => console.log(this.state.races));
```

Or you can `console.log` your state in your `render` method.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from official docs:

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

**Important!**

> This makes reading `this.state` right after calling setState() a **potential pitfall**.

So you will not get state immediately after `setState`. You have 2 ways to solve it.

1) You should check in `componentDidUpdate` hook.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(this.state.races);//your data updated here.
}
```

You can see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to use properly.

2) Or you use `callback` in `setState` like this `setState(updater, callback)`:

```
this.setState({races:data_mapped}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.races)//your data updated here.
})
```

Comment: Nice explanation with quotes, but maybe there are more ways than two :) Also, `componentDidUpdate` is like killing a fly with a sledgehammer :) At least for me since we can do it in the `render` method easily.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But the `render()` function should be pure :)

Comment: Why? Maybe you can say that for `return` but you can run lots of logic in the `render` method. Use functions, variables, etc. Also, this is a simple `console.log`.  Also, I'm saying "You should not use any lifecycle method unless it is really needed" :) By the way, don't misunderstand me please, I'm the one upvoted your answer.

Comment: Yes, in your situation that is true, I usually do like that. **should be pure** means that we should not edit, update `state` at here :)

Comment: Oh, yes. We really, really should not update the state in `render`. But logging is OK :)

Comment: @ Max thanks. actually i've still not been able to ensure setState is actually being called after the data is changed from the API call. I've removed the console.log statements and tried adding this:  this.setState(() => {races:data_mapped}) to the processResults function